# How to return previous fragment by calling activity's onBackPress()

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

I have an activity with two fragments added to it using :

```
fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment){

    private val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
    val fragmentTag  = fragment::class.simpleName.toString()
    val ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()

    ft.add(R.id.fragments_container, fragment,fragmentTag)
    ft.addToBackStack(fragmentTag)
    ft.commit()

}
```

I add two fragments A and B to activity with this order:
A  ---> B

when i press back button on phone it return from B to A as expected

but the problem is that when i call activity's **onBackPressed** method when clicking on a view for example:

```
imgBack.setOnClickListener {
   onBackPressed()
}
```

**it does not work like when i press back button on the phone

it returns to fragment A but not showing fragment A views as expected.**

onBackPressed:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {

    if (fragmentManager.backStackEntryCount > 1) {
        fragmentManager.popBackStack()
    } else {
        finish()
    }
   }
```

Comment: Try `super.onBackPressed()` on image click and remove custom implementation.

Comment: @Ranjan i have tried it but not worked

Answer (score 0):

if you `imgBack` are in `fragmentB` call

```
imgBack.setOnClickListener {
activity?.onBackPressed()
}
```

Comment: are onBackPressed implementation are on the Activity which holds the two fragments

Comment: yes onBackPressed is in the activity which hold two fragments A and B

Comment: I have reproduced your scenario and things seems to work fine ,can you give more details on how you adds fragments and how your fragmentA is shows with this unexpected case